# Rails model testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, model

Hello I am using rspec to test my user model. I just wanted to know if what I am doing is a common practice in testing. To test for error messages I am doing something like this

```
    User.create!(users(:first))
    user.update_attributes  email: 'IDon\'tThinkThisIsAValidEmail' 
    user.should_not be_valid
    assert user.errors.messages.include? :email
```

Also how would I go about testing for duplicates? Calling full_messages and testing for "Email has already been taken" message? Is this a good practice. I am doing tests this way because before my should_not be_valid tests were passing because the username was invalid so that was no good. IS what I am doing a good idea? Any better ways of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validating the format of an email you can do something like the following. Note that you don't have to create a user record or use fixtures for writing most validation specs.

```
    it "will not allow invalid email addresses" do
      user = User.new(email: 'notAValidEmail')
      user.should have(1).error_on(:email)
    end

    it "will allow valid email addresses" do
      user = User.new(email: 'valid@email.com')
      user.should have(:no).errors_on(:email)
    end
```

For validating presence you can do this:

```
    it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
```

You can see the rspec documentation for more examples:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/model-specs/errors-on

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda), which has a suite of useful test assertions, including for uniqueness validations:

```
describe User do
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)
end
```

Edit: [Here's a link to the docs as a great place to start](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames).

Comment: Beat me to it :) I was also going to recommend the docs as a good place to start http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames